# Undefined function is working at second click (with an error)

Tags: php, function, undefined

I'm trying to add someone when they get a friendshiprequest. I created a function to accept or decline that person. But when I klik on fe 'accept' he does nothing, the second time he executes the sql function en sets the friendshipstatus from 'pending' to 'accepted' BUT I always get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function AcceptFriendRequest() in C:\wamp\www\Stimulus\friendrequests.php on line 82
```

SQL

```
UPDATE friendship SET friendship_status = 'Accepted' WHERE friendship_id ='101'
```

FUNCTION (in the class friendship)

```
public function AcceptFriendRequest($requestnumber){
        $db = new Db();
        $select = "UPDATE friendship SET friendship_status = 'Accepted' WHERE friendship_id ='" . $requestnumber . "'";  
    echo $select;
        $result = $db->conn->query($select);
        return $result;}
```

PHP

```
$user = new User();
$friendship = new Friendship();
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$numberoffriendrequests = $friendship->GetTotalOfFriendRequests($user_id);
$friendrequests=$friendship->GetAllFriendRequests($email);

    if (isset($_POST["Accept"])) {
    try {


        $requestnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acceptID']);
        $friendship -> AcceptFriendRequest($requestnumber);
        $feedback = "Awesome, You just added a friend!";


    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage();

    }
}

    if (isset($_POST["Decline"])) {
    try {


        $requestnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['declineID']);
        $friendship -> DeleteFriendRequest($requestnumber);
        $feedback = "You just deleted a friend!";


    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage();

    }
}
```

MY PRINT OUT, my error has to be on this line:  `$accepted = AcceptFriendRequest($_POST['acceptid']);`

```
 <?php
    foreach ($friendrequests as $request) {
    echo "
        <div><p>
            <a href='profile.php?user_id=".$request['friendship_applicant_id'] . "'>
                <img src='uploads/" . $request['friendship_applicant_avatar']  . " " . " ' alt='' />" . $request['friendship_applicant_surname'] . $request['friendship_id'] . " " . $request['friendship_applicant_name'] . "
            </a> has send you a friend request" . "

            <form action='" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "' method='post'>
                <button type='submit' name='Accept'>Accept</button>
                <button type='submit' name='Decline'>Decline</button>
                <input type='hidden' name='acceptID' value='".$request['friendship_id']."' />
                <input type='hidden' name='declineID' value='".$request['friendship_id']."' />
            </form>
        </p></div>";   
    }//foreach

    if (isset($_POST['Accept'])){
        $accepted = AcceptFriendRequest($_POST['acceptid']);

        //echo $accepted;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Decline'])){
          $decline = DeclineFriendRequest($_POST['declineid']);
    }
```

Comment: You are calling  `AcceptFriendRequest` without any object of that class?

Comment: something like this: $friendship->AcceptFriendRequest($requestnumber); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here-

```
 if (isset($_POST['Accept'])){
        $accepted = AcceptFriendRequest($_POST['acceptid']);

        //echo $accepted;
    }
```

Its outside the class and only an object of that class can make a call to that method!  Until ofcoasre if you define the method static, after which you can call it by scope resolution operator!

You can Either use an object to access that method or just define you method static and access by-

```
classname::functionname();
```

If you like to call the method by object-

```
 if (isset($_POST['Accept'])){
            $accepted = $friendship->AcceptFriendRequest($_POST['acceptid']);

            //echo $accepted;
        }
```

Comment: I see, stupid from my side BUT when I click the first time it is updating the database but also giving me this error: Notice: Undefined index: acceptid in C:\wamp\www\Jiii\friendrequests.php on line 83

At the second click the notice stays but the 2 buttons (decline, accept) dissapear

Comment: var_dump $_POST and see what values it hold, if it isnt having acceptid then look for the page from where you are making this post request

Comment: i really cant understand why you are making get and post request on the same page! better only use one

Comment: everything is working now, but it i have to click twice before the buttons dissapear... :s

Comment: Get = user_id from url?
Post = to push something to db?

Comment: can you tell me the flow of your program from the beginning. what is happening after when? by this, it will be easier to debug

Comment: I solved it... 
I placed this: $numberoffriendrequests = $friendship->GetTotalOfFriendRequests($user_id);
$friendrequests=$friendship->GetAllFriendRequests($email); after my posts..

Comment: glad that you finally got your answer! :-)